# Partial Differential Formatting by default

Tags: output-formatting

I read

http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/15/mathematica-qa-series-converting-to-conventional-mathematical-typesetting/

and I could use `pdConv` mentioned there, or

```
pdConv[f_] :=  TraditionalForm[ f /.Derivative[inds__][g_][vars__] :>
                 Apply[Defer[D[g[vars], ##]] &,
                 Transpose[{{vars}, {inds}}] /. {{var_, 0} :>    
                 Sequence[], {var_, 1} :> {var}}]]
```

What I wonder is, is there any way to implement this setting by default output format in my notebook?

I am currently modified my output in Option Inspector so that it will always be printed as `TraditionalForm`, but I want partial derivative appear as $\partial / \partial x$.

Also, is there any way to make it appear as $\partial _x$?

Comment: Is it OK to apply this across the current session?  If so I believe merely setting `$PrePrint = pdConv;` will do what you want.  If you want this only to apply to a specific Notebook that is more work using `CellEpilog`.